# Confused by "presently came in for" in a sentence

Tags: expressions

I was reading *Security Analysis* and I was confused by the following sentence:

> what was left of them presently came in for rough handling of the first Roosevelt administration

I know that the meaning of the sentence is "the only thing left for them is the first Roosevelt administration", **but what does the phrase "presently came in for" mean in the sentence?**

Comment: Please provide more context and make sure you copied the text correctly.

Comment: *presently* means *soon* for many educated writers. What else puzzles you?

Comment: [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/come-in-for) has a good definition of the transitive multi-word verb 'come in for'.

Comment: 'for rough handling of the first Roosevelt administration' sound a bit, well, rough.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - what?

Comment: @YosefBaskin - disagree with both.

Comment: We are in for a hard time with this pandemic . . .

Comment: "Came in for" means "were subjected to". "Presently" means "later but not all that much  later" or "soon" as @Xanne says above. Personally I think that "presently" implies a rather longer delay than "soon" but it's still a shorter rather than  a longer one. A lot shorter than "eventually" anyway.

Comment: Is the core of what is confusing you the fact that the author uses *presently* is describing past events?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe the sentence means "the only thing left for them is the first Roosevelt administration"

"What was left of them" refers to the remains of some process whether a disaster, reduction or battle. The larger part has been removed or eliminated. What remains is what is left, the survivors. This may be people or profits at the start of the story.

"Came in for rough handling" means the survivors of the first process were handled roughly. Here, roughly is an idiom for poorly or unpleasantly which is meant by roughly to appear as violence. That may be money taxed way too much or people dealt with in an unkind fashion. The first Roosevelt administration was known to do that with both people and profits.

"Presently" means at that time or that just following, in that present or in the next moment. "I finished my answer and presently was reminded by jsw29 that I should answer the question."

Comment: This explains all aspects of the quoted text except the use of *presently*, which may be precisely the aspect that is confusing the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your time! It is indeed the word "presently" that makes me puzzled. Another reply said: "presently means soon for many educated writers.", maybe I'm not well educated haha